# Eliminar registo da base de dados

Tags: sql

Estou a tentar executar a seguinte linha:

```
 $sqld = "delete FROM ata where convocatoria.nome_entidade='$ent'   and convocatoria.cod_convocatoria=ata.cod_convocatoria";
 mysql_query($sqld);
```

Tentei direto no phpmyadmin e deu o seguinte erro:

> Unknown column 'convocatoria.nome_entidade' in 'where clause'

se executar:

```
$sqld = "select * FROM ata,convocatoria where convocatoria.nome_entidade='Spa'     and convocatoria.cod_convocatoria=ata.cod_convocatoria ";
mysql_query($sqld);
```

Funciona mas ele faz `select * from convocatoria`, o problema no delete deve estar aí.

Tabela convocatoria:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Tabela ata:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei no manual do phpMyAdmin e achei a solução:

```
DELETE ata, convocatoria FROM ata INNER JOIN convocatoria 
WHERE convocatoria.nome_entidade='sdasd' 
  AND convocatoria.cod_convocatoria=ata.cod_convocatoria
```